# UIWebView stopped getting JS events in shouldStartLoadWith under Swift3

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, swift3, xcode8, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm using UIWebView in my application for some reasons that WKWebView can't fit for me.
Explaining that, I just finished with my application conversion to Swift3 (Was 2.2) and my `shouldStartLoadWith` functions not getting the JS event.
If i run my previous build before the conversion - everything working perfect.

My code look like this:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        let url:URL = request.url!
        if (url.scheme == "something"){

            if (url.host != nil){
                var properString = url.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding!
                properString = properString.replacingOccurrences(of: "something://", with: "")
                performJSFunction(message: properString)
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true
    }
```

**note**: nothing changes in the server side/html page.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries i have found out that the `UIWebView` will get events with `https://` or `http://`in the beginning.

so if you used to get it like this:

```
appname://something
```

now you should get it like this:

```
https://appname//something
```

(pay attention that the dots after the "appname" will be remove automatically - even if you will send it via `src attribute`.

i know it's not what you wanted to be - but it works really good.

Comment: And how exactly I'm supposed to get an https/http from a local HTML file? Any ideas to help?

Comment: if i understand your question i just made it like this: if i get a url started with the src attribute i selected (as described in my answer) i didn't let it continue with the process and if not - i acting like a regular url

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to do the same job but using **local** `html` files this doesn't have nothing to do with `https://` or `http://`.

The solution was changing the `<button>` to the `<a>` tag.

```
<a onclick="interface.callFromJS()" href="inapp://capture" ontouchstart="">Your Button Message</a>
```

And then you'll be able to catch these events there:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        if (request.url?.scheme == "inapp")
        {
            doYourAction()      
        }

        return true

    }
```

Hope it helps someone.